# Phonegap Build cordova how to detect no internet connection even wifi connected

Tags: cordova, connection, status

Using `Phonegap Build` for `iOS` application, How to detect if there is no internet connection on the device even a `wifi/wireless` connection exist and the device itself is connection to wifi connection but no response from the internet.

There is an activity in the application, needs to connect to the internet to get an online image, so the device is connection to wireless connection but no internet response, we want to check that instead of the loader indication icon still appeared!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [Network Information Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/df7aac845dc7deddbdb76e89216776a802ee8b67/doc/index.md)

Comment: Yes, i did. It's already used. But the problem still exist, because the plugin did not indicated if the internet is working or not, it just inform if a connection type exists like (2g,3g,4g,wifi,ethernet...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use google's blank page : http://www.google.fr/blank.html

A function to test this address to check if the device has access to internet would look like this :

```
function testInternet(win,fail){
    $.get("http://www.google.fr/blank.html").done(win).fail(fail);
}
```

Or if you need to specify a timeout shorter than the default one :

```
function testInternet(win,fail){
    $.ajax({
         url:"http://www.google.fr/blank.html",
         timeout:5000,   //timeout to 5s
         type: "GET",
         cache: false
       }).done(win).fail(fail); 
}
```

Comment: This operation is working right and favorable, but could we reduce the time of response from server, because it takes a times to indicate that's failed!

Comment: yes, use $.ajax instead of $.get and specify a timeout param

Comment: This approach does not work on Cafe-internets which have this annoying "Welcome to Cafe X. Click to connect"